# Magento 1.9 Custom Bundle Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options, bundled-product

I have a little question regarding bundle products, but I don't know how to achieve this custom scenario...
in a magento 1.9.3.4 Shop which sales juice boxes:
A juice box contains six juices(not more and not less).
The customer can choose between 10 different juices (there will come more) to fill each of the six slots in the juice box.

Is it the best way to add 6 options (juice box slot 1 to 6) to a bundle product and each one contains all different juices?

It feels a bit cumbersome because if there is a new juice I have to add it to each of the six options.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem with best practices are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Configurable Bundle](https://www.wizkunde.nl/configurable-bundle.html) is an extension that will let you include configurable products in your bundled product.

You can setup Juice 1 - Juice 6, each with the same 10 options. This will allow the customer to choose one juice from each and have no more or less than 6 selected.

You may need to make other adjustments (like minimum quantity) so the customer does not try to add them to the cart without selecting all 6.

---

Alternatively, you could build 6 attributes: juice1 - juice6; all with the same options. Then create a configurable product that has all 6 juice attributes included & have the customer select 1 from each of the attributes.

Comment: But the addition of new juice is the same... i have to add it 6 times. That feels weird. I just saw [Flexible Bundle Product](https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/flexible-bundle-product.html) which could handle this. maybe i give it a shot. but thank a lot

Comment: The only problem I've run into with bundles, is customers being able to set a QTY to 0 and then add only one product to the cart. This really hurts if your "Bundled" price is lower than the individual. The extension you noted looks like it might handle it well. Post an answer if it does the trick for you :)